# LINQ multiple childs in 1 row

Tags: c#, sql, linq

My tables are structured as below:

**Questions**

```
id  title
1   what is this?
```

**Answers**

```
id   answer qid
1    an     1
```

I want to select the question and all the answers in one single row through LINQ?

How can i do this?

Comment: "one single row"?  That doesn't make sense for a one-to-many relationship.  Did you mean a single *object*?  Also, are you using Linq-To-Sql?

Comment: what is the expected output[specific]. Give that also, so that people can answer accordingly.

Comment: output must be as follows:
questionid, question,answer1,answer2,answer3...

Comment: updated my answer to address your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Hasan's answer, if you are using LinqToSql and your relationships are properly established, then the code should simply be:

```
var question = questions.Single(x => x.Id == 3);
```

Answers should then *already* be available to you through the property:

```
var answers = question.Answers;
```

Since presumably you have an actual relationship defined between `question.Id` and `answer.Qid`.

**Update:**

In response to OP's comments, here is how you can get all the data back as one row:

```
var questionAndAnswers = questions
    .Where(x => x.Id == 3)
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        QuestionId = x.Id, 
        Question = x.Title, 
        Answer1 = x.Answers[0].Answer,
        Answer2 = x.Answers[1].Answer,
        Answer3 = x.Answers[2].Answer
    }).Single();
```

Will return an object with the question and 3 answers.  Obviously adding more answers requires tweaking this statement, since it's flattened.

Comment: thanks kirk. oops i forgot linq can do this .. anyway thanks for the reminder :)